# Convert categorical strings to integers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-conversion

I have a vector  that has labels with a `char` i would like to conver these to integers.
Example:

```
Y | Y^
--+--
A | 1
A | 1
B | 2
C | 3
B | 2
B | 2
A | 1
C | 2
```

I have `Y` and i would like to convert to `Y^`. Any function or suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bellow code snippet should produce the desired results:
`Y^ = grp2idx(Y)`

Answer (score 3):

As [**`grp2idx`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/grp2idx.html) requires the **Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox** I'd recommend a little simpler solution:

```
y = Y - 64

%// or alternatively (thanks to EBH)
y = Y - 'A' + 1
```

A `char` is nothing else than an 8-bit integer mapping [**ASCII-Code**](http://www.asciitable.com/), where capital letters start with 65.

Comment: I would have written `'A'+1` instead of 64, for a clearer interpretation